# How do I set margins to zero in a uitableviewcell?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, ios8

As seen in the link below theres some margin/padding on the top, bottom, left and right part of a cell. How do I set it to zero? I tried returning `CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)` in the `-(CGRect)layoutMargins` margin of the `UITableViewCell`'s lifecycle.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rl95v2688k70u0j/Screenshot%202014-10-13%2003.29.08.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `AutoLayout` (which seems to be the case according to your screenshot) you can reach this be modifying the constraints (the blue lines which you see in Interface Builder). `AutoLayout` can be tough to deal with at the beginning, but if follows quite logical structures. If you want to get down on the nitty gritty of it and understand how it works I can recommend you this [excellent video tutorial from Scotty on the topic](http://vimeo.com/77600524).

Another simple way would be to turn off `AutoLayout` and just set the label to the same size of your cell, so your approach with `CGRectMake` isn't all that wrong, except that you need to keep in mind that it takes as parameters: x and y coordinates (which you want to set to 0 as you already did) but also width and height (which you also set to 0, but probably want to set equal to the cell's size).

`AutoLayout` can be turned off in Interface Builder by removing the checkmark in the following picture:
[image]

Comment: but I set the vertical space constraint to 0, as seen here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk6fwh4o931f2ia/Screenshot%202014-10-13%2004.08.42.png?dl=0 and here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ca0tjj1ahfa2tf/Screenshot%202014-10-13%2004.10.38.png?dl=0

Comment: figured it out will post my answer in a bit, thanks for the help!